# Darle formato json a datos

Tags: php, json

Tengo este código que lo que hace es realizar búsquedas con unos api.

Quisiera darle formato json para que sea más amigable a la hora de hacer consultas y pintar los datos.

Actualmente me devuelve la información así:

```
Array
(
    [
    0
] => Array
        (
            [nombre
] => The Mixed Tape
            [longDescription
] => 
            [imagen
] => https: //video-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/Video128/v4/f9/9b/55/f99b554c-24fa-136f-5bb4-0590931573d6/mzvf_5528930120957315186.640x480.h264lc.D2.p.m4v [busquedaobtenidade
] => itunes
        )

    [
    1
] => Array
        (
            [nombre
] => You And Your Heart
            [longDescription
] => 
            [imagen
] => https: //video-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/Video115/v4/f0/92/0c/f0920ce2-8bb7-5e62-b44c-36ce701fe7b1/mzvf_6922739671336234286.640x352.h264lc.U.p.m4v [busquedaobtenidade
] => itunes
        )

)
```

Pero quisiera que me devuelva así la información en un formato más limpio:

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
  "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
}
```

Éste es mi código PHP:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

$a_resultados = array(); 
$counter = 0;

// $search_val = $_GET['search_val'];

if (!empty($_GET['search_val'])) {
    $search_val = $_GET['search_val'];
    $content=file_get_contents("https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=" .$search_val. "&entity=musicVideo");
    $json = json_decode($content);
    // print_r($json);
    foreach ($json->results as $res) {
        $a_resultados[$counter]["nombre"] = $res->trackName; 
        $a_resultados[$counter]["longDescription"] = $res->longDescription; 
        $a_resultados[$counter]["imagen"] = $res->previewUrl; 
        $a_resultados[$counter]["busquedaobtenidade"] = "itunes"; 
        $counter++;
    }

    $contenttwo = file_get_contents("http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=".$search_val);
    $jsontwo = json_decode($contenttwo,true);

    //print_r($jsontwo);

    foreach ($jsontwo as $res) {
        $a_resultados[$counter]["nombre"] = $res["show"]["name"]; 
        $a_resultados[$counter]["longDescription"] = $res["show"]["summary"]; 
        $a_resultados[$counter]["imagen"] = $res["show"]["url"]; 
        $a_resultados[$counter]["busquedaobtenidade"] = "tv maze";
        $counter++;
    }
}

if (!empty($_GET['search_val'])) {
    print_r($a_resultados);
    // print_r(json_encode($a_resultados));
    // print_r(json_decode(json_encode($a_resultados)));
} else {
    print_r("Ingrese una busqueda, por ejemplo ?search_val=jack ");
}

?>
<?php

?>
```

Comment: ¿Pudiste comprobar alguna de las respuestas que te indicamos?

Answer (score 1):

Sustituye tus `print_r` por `echo`

En cuanto a tu resultado imprimelo asi

```
echo json_encode($a_resultados);
```

acerca del comentario de la url:

```js
var elJson = '{"url":"http:\/\/www.tvmaze.com\/shows\/3661\/jack-irish"}';
var elObj = JSON.parse(elJson);
console.log(elObj)
document.write(`<a href="${elObj.url}">${elObj.url}</a>`)
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta,

Si me funciona aunque me devulve valores como
 
http:\/\/www.tvmaze.com\/shows\/3661\/jack-irish

sabes como poner que se vea normal las urls

Comment: El formato json coloca asi las url para poder interpretar `/` como un caracter, no hay otra forma

Comment: Como aportacion,  si por ejemplo estas usando del lado del frontend JS, cuando la data sea parseada,  esas barras \/, no apareceran a menos que hagan parte explicitamente de tu json (es decir que tu las hayas colocado).

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo comentarios en el código:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

if (empty($_GET['search_val']) === false) {
    /* Inicializa la variable */
    $a_resultados = [];
    /* No uses variables transitorias innecesarias y usa urlencode() */
    $content = file_get_contents(
       "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=". urlencode($_GET['search_val']) ."&entity=musicVideo"
    );
    $json = json_decode($content);
    foreach ($json->results as $res) {
        /* Agregamos un elemento nuevo a los datos */
        array_push($a_resultados, [
            "nombre" => $res->trackName,
            "longDescription" => $res->longDescription,
            "imagen" => $res->previewUrl,
            "busquedaobtenidade" => "itunes",
        ]);
    }

    /* No olvides urlencode() */
    $contenttwo = file_get_contents(
        "http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=". urlencode($_GET['search_val'])
    );
    $jsontwo = json_decode($contenttwo, true);

    foreach ($jsontwo as $res) {
        /* Agregamos un elemento nuevo a los datos */
        array_push($a_resultados, [
            "nombre" => $res["show"]["name"],
            "longDescription" => $res["show"]["summary"],
            "imagen" => $res["show"]["url"],
            "busquedaobtenidade" => "tv maze",
        ]);
    }
    /* Declaramos el tipo de datos entregados y finalizamos tras enviarlos al navegador */
    header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    die(json_encode($a_resultados, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
}
?><p>Ingrese una busqueda, por ejemplo <code>?search_val=jack</code></p>
```

Te destaco los siguientes puntos:

- Debes declarar el tipo de dato entregado con la cabecera HTTP `Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8`.
- Puedes exportar datos nativos de PHP en formato JSON a través de la función [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode), pero debes usar una función de salida para enviar el resultado al navegador, como `echo` o `die()`. No uses `print_r()` ni `var_export()` ni funciones que alteren el contenido exacto del resultado.
- Escapa siempre los datos `GET` agregados a una URL mediante [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode).
- Evita el uso de variables transitorias, son un mal hábito y proclives a errores.